# Creating Pause Button for Windows Phone Stopwatch timer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I have created the stop and start buttons but wasn't able to create the pause/resume buttons. Can someone please provide me some hint/code on how to approach these methods?

P.S.: The other problem my code has is that its timer increases by 1000 rather than 1! Any clue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;
namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int time;
        DateTime currentTime= new DateTime();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

            long elapseTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks - currentTime.Ticks;
            TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(elapseTime);
            textClock.Text = elapsedSpan.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0.00");
        }

        private void Button_Stop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            newTimer.Stop();
        }

        private void Button_Pause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //newTimer.Stop(); ??
         }

        private void Button_Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
            newTimer.Start();


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: The timer increases by 1000 because you are setting exactly that with `newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` line. Basic unit for timers is milisecond, not second.

Comment: @S_F Thanks for your help. Now it works fine. Any idea about the pause button?

Comment: Sorry, if I had one, I'd be writing a proper answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to implement it. The first one is the using of the Stopwatch class to measure time.

```
public partial class MainPage
  : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 / 30);
        newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    }

    void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        UpdateUI();
    }

    private void Button_Stop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stop();
    }

    private void Button_Pause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pause();
    }

    private void Button_Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Start();
    }

    void UpdateUI()
    {
        textClock.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("0.00");
    }

    void Start()
    {
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        newTimer.Start();
        UpdateUI();
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        sw.Stop();
        newTimer.Stop();
        UpdateUI();
    }

    void Pause()
    {
        Stop();
    }

    void Resume()
    {
         sw.Start();
         newTimer.Start();
         UpdateUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't have a Resume method in stopwatch class. But the Start method can also resume. Do you know how can I use its Start method to resume? `Starts, or resumes, measuring elapsed time for an interval.` Thanks.

Comment: Also there was no Restart in sw mthods while it is mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx that there should be also a Restart method. Do you know what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It was written without MSDN, I don't remember it on the 100% :) So, code was fixed.